# twillio studio send message flow contact.channel

Tags: twilio

I have a twillio sms message flow that is working just fine.  I just want a small improvement but not sure where to look.  In the below snip on line two, I would like to send the caller id (contact.channel.callerId???) vs the number (contact.channel.address)

```
{% if  trigger.message.Body  %}
SMS from {{contact.channel.address}}: 
{{  trigger.message.Body }}
{% else %}
A call was received from:  
{{contact.channel.address}}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach and used some if statements.   It may not be as elegant but it works:

```
{% if  trigger.message.Body  %}
{% if contact.channel.address %}
{% if  contact.channel.address ==  '+18558675309' %}
Jack says: {{ trigger.message.Body }}
{% endif %}
{% if  contact.channel.address ==  '+18558675309' %}
Buddy says: {{ trigger.message.Body }}
{% endif %}
{% else %}
Unknown says: {{ trigger.message.Body }}
{% endif %}
{% else %}
A call was received from:  
{{contact.channel.address}}
{% endif %}
```